# Integration over n-sphere

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I am trying to integrate squares of sum of coordinates in n-dimensional sphere with radius bounded by r.

$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. In spherical coordinates when $N=2,\;y=a\cos\theta$ and $x=a\sin\theta$

So my question becomes 
$$
\int_0^r \int (a\cos\theta + a\sin\theta)^2da\,d\theta\,.
$$

$\theta$ between 0 and $2\pi$.

I calculated this analytically by using symmetries around $y=-x$ in $\mathbb R^2$ but if someone has a general formula for this particular integral in n dimension it would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't you asking to integrate a constant function (radius squared) over the sphere of radius $r$, so it'd just be $r^2$ times the total "area" of the sphere?

Comment: I think it is not a constant function. It includes all the points inside the ball too. For n=2 case I computed it equals to pi*(4r^3)/3. I calculate integral above between 0 to pi/2 and between pi and 3pi/2 and then multiply the sum by 2. By computing (2^N)/2 quadrants in N-dimensional ball I can do it by brute force. But it is an insane calculation. That is why I am looking for a general formula or a rule to make it simpler